# Hibernate creates different ID than H2

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I have a table in a h2 database. When I try to insert a new entry with hibernate and spring boot, the object has a a different ID than the one in the table itself (I look it up after the insert in hibernate). I do the insert with an interface that extends the class "CrudRepository". AUTO_INCREMENT is turned on in my table, the java class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupchat")
public class GroupChat {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long groupChatID;

   .....
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can make Hibernate to give me the same ID as H2 does?

Comment: What do you mean: the generated id should depend on the current content of the database, or the values in the bean that is inserted, or some other kind of computation? What should be important with technical ids / primary keys is that they are unique within their scope. If you expect the id to have one given value, then do not rely on `GenerationType.AUTO`.

Comment: The generated ID should be the same ID as in the database, since I need to do more processing after my insert, and if its not correct it won't be found in the DB